# How to set text of multiple buttons using a for loop and the contents of an ArrayList - Java - Android

Tags: java, android, button, arraylist

I currently have 35 buttons, not all of which will be used by the final product.
I also have an arraylist with a variety of items:

```
ArrayList textBlobs = new ArrayList();
```

```
textBlobs.add("text");
textBlobs.add("two");
textBlobs.add("tt");
textBlobs.add("txt");
textBlobs.add("te");
textBlobs.add("tet");
textBlobs.add("go");
textBlobs.add("eat");
textBlobs.add("spring");
textBlobs.add("rolls");
textBlobs.add("egu77$");
```

I also have 35 buttons called buttonx with x being a number 0 through 34 (35 total)

```
private Button button0, button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9, button10, button11, button12, button13,
        button14, button15, button16, button17, button18, button19, button20, button21, button22, button23, button24, button25, button26, button27,
        button28, button29, button30, button31, button32, button33, button34;
```

These buttons have already been initialized and declared using root.findByViewId(R.id.button_)

Here I have a for loop that simply runs through the textBlobs ArrayList. As of right now, all the buttons have no text (""). I want to use this for loop to set buttons 0 through textBlobs.size() to the text contained within textBlobs at that index.

```
for(int i = 0; i < textBlobs.size(); i++ ) {

        }
```

Not all of the buttons will be used and that is the goal, this should be able to be used with an ArrayList of any length up to 35. I am stuck as to how I should be setting the text. As far as I know the only way to set the text of a button is to use

```
button0.setText("insert text");
```

which would not work in my case because I cannot make the number part of the name change between each instance of the for loop.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the best solution whould be using an array of Buttons

```
ArrayList<Button> btns = new ArrayList<Button>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add all the buttons to an ArrayList and work with it.